How do Non-deterministic signatures in wallets leak key material
Downsides of not using deterministic ECDSA signatures for blockchain validation? here in the last answer it says:
"With non-deterministic signatures, your hardware wallet might be leaking key material. The only way for users to verify this is not happening is to try your brand wallet with deterministically signing implementations and compare if the signatures match. In other words, hardware wallets not using deterministic signing should be considered insecure"
Please explain this in more detail. Why "leaking key material"? What specific scenario might be insecure?

The problem arises if the "random value" is actually reused, i.e. when the random number generator does not behave well. In principle constrained / embedded devices can host a pretty good TRNG / DRBG combination - most smart cards do - but this may not be the case for constrained IoT devices. In that case it is easy to recompute the private key if you have two message / signature pairs, as it leads to an equation that can be solved.
It's not necessarily true that you'd require a deterministic signature generator to work around this issue. As long as the message itself can help to randomize the generation of the values of $k$ and $r$ then the equation cannot be solved without breaking ECC. Deterministic signatures are one way to do this, but e.g. EdDSA (using the Ed25519 or Ed448 curves) does use both a hash as well as a random value.
As the random value contains many bits it is extremely unlikely that a non-determinstic implementation of ECDSA will ever generate the same signature. Of course, the only time it does that is if the signature generation fails. So you'd have to perform two times the signing without restarting the hardware wallet, as otherwise you may confuse a deterministic wallet with one that is actually failing.
As indicated, a non-deterministic wallet may well be secure. However, a wallet that uses deterministic signing will at least not have this particular vulnerability. And remember, there is more to security than this particular issue.
